# How to call back to main thread to enable a button from a backgroundworker thread

Tags: c#, wpf, button, backgroundworker, isenabled

I have a background worker that gets called to do some work and in that background worker I want to enable a `Button`:

```
myButton.IsEnabled = true;
```

In my UI (main thread). What do I need to do to make thecall back to the main thread to do this?

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to your object from the background worker thread you can dispatch the enabling of the button to your UI thread using [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) method like this :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
{
    myButton.IsEnabled = true;
}, null);
```